# Check checkbox if certain conditions are met excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a simple vba userform with a couple of checkboxes to hide certain data, so different people can select which data they would like to see.
While searching i started wondering if its possible to automatically check the boxes when i run an initial macro if certain criteria are met.
Right now this is my code for that macro;

---

```
Sub userform_Open()

Dim Project As CheckBox

Selection.Show vbModeless 
   'to show the options so the user can choose which data he sees.

If Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
   'If this column is shown i want "project" (checkbox) to be ticked on, so the user knows it is shown.
    Project.Value = True
    Else
    Project.Value = False
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Its a simple macro, but i can't find anything online that works... it keeps giving me a "run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't `Dim Project As CheckBox` this creates a variable `Project` that is not linked to your user form checkbox.
  Instead make sure you use the name of your checkbox here `Me.MyCheckboxName.Value = True`. `Me` points to the userform the code is written in.
- Further Excel cannot know in which worksheet `Columns("F")` is if you don't specify it like:

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("F")
  ```
- Finally if your userform is named `Selection` choose another name for it. `Selection` is a reserved key word in VBA and must not be used for variable or userform names.

So something like this should work:

```
Sub userform_Open()        
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless 'make sure to replace `UserForm1` with your form name don't use `Selection` as form name!

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
        'If this column is shown i want "project" (checkbox) to be ticked on, so the user knows it is shown.
        Me.CheckBoxName.Value = True 'make sure `CheckBoxName` is the name of your checkbox
    Else
        Me.CheckBoxName.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Since my excel file has all its data on the first page the Me.name.value change was the only edit that i needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no "Open" event in Userform, so I guess the code may not be in the userform code. Then `Me` won't points to the userform.

Comment: @VincentG well if the code is in the userform scope `Me` will still work. And yes, good point, you are right the OP probably want's to use the `UserForm_Initialize` event which runs automatically. A `userform_Open` indeed does not exist.

Comment: @BartV. *"has all its data on the first page"* that is no reason to write unreliable code. Instead it is a good practice to write solid code. What if in 2 years you add another sheet and then your code stops working and you have no idea why. If you can prevent that today by specifying the sheet explicitly. Do it!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm still learning myself the different things with vba but sometimes i get stuck (like here). also big thanks to the comments, learned from them, too :)